# Delete the 2 Top Row and put transcript underneath

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nlp

Working on a large datasets. i am stuck at the data clearning stage

Here's what i have so far.. I just want to delete the "Issuegroup and Feedback" which looks like in the top 2 rows

```py
                                    Feedback
Out[39]: Issuegroup
         Accessories                Nope, just make a longer charging cord :),Everything was very helpful and nice handled,Nope, you guys are doing great,From the customer's side, th...
         Connectivity               no suggestions. Chat experience was great!,Jane was wonderful and would recommend her to a friend, she helped me get through some troubleshooting...


and output of below and if i can view the entire content of Accessories or Connectivity since i have 4,200 comments underneath           


Out[39]:                            transcript   
         Accessories                Nope, just make a longer charging cord :),Everything was very helpful and nice handled,Nope, you guys are doing great,From the customer's side, th...
         Connectivity               no suggestions. Chat experience was great!,Jane was wonderful and would recommend her to a friend, she helped me get through some troubleshooting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None).rename(columns={'Feedback':'transcript'})
```

Columns name is always necessary in `DataFrame`, so is possible rename it to empty string - but it is really awful trick, dont use it.

Comment: thanks for the input jezrael. do you have recommendations prior doing it?

Comment: @RollyV. - Not sure if understand, code working like you need?